# HERE traffic API Status Codes for Request Response

Tags: here-api

The Speed Data Rest API Specification lists the Response status as:

Possible values for status are:
• Pending
• In Progress
• Completed Successfully
• Completed With Error
• Rejected

The statusCode from the response returns a System.Net.HttpStatusCode, which doesn't include any of the above.

Similarly, the Response.ResponseStatus returns an IRestResponse.ResponseStatus which doesn't return any of the above either.

The only other status item returned is the string, Response.StatusDescription. Is that what is set to Pending, In Progress etc?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Is this sorted at your end now ? Can you please elucidate more which API being used, etc..?

Comment: The API endpoint is https://trafficanalytics.api.here.com/dailyAnalytics/requests

Answer (score 0):

Oops, dumb question.

The items I was trying to match to the request status are the *response* status values. The *request* status is different and returns:

400 Bad Request
401 Unauthorized
403 Forbidden
413 Payload Too Large

The first three of these are in the System.Net.HttpStatusCode.StatusCode returned by the request.